# Browser redirect loop detection

Tags: browser, redirect

How do browsers (in general) detect a redirect loop? And how big a chain can they handle? It is kind of easy to detect a two way redirect loop, but what about a chain of 4, or 5? - Is it just an array algorithm which will work on a chain of any length?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's even simpler than that - most browsers I've seen will simply give up after following a set maximum number of redirects. For instance, if you have a rewrite rule which always adds "x" to the end of the URL:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) /$1x [R]
```

Chrome will give up once it hits `/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` - 21 redirects total.

Comment: Firefox 10 gives up after 21 redirections as well. According to [rfc2616 10.3](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3) older versions of the HTTP protocol recommended a 5 redirection limit, so it is not safe to assume the browser will handle more than that.